# Webscraping and decoding string into pandas DF

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, robobrowser

I'm webscraping and would like to have a Pandas dataframe as a result of my content scraping. I'm able to get an `UTF-8` string that I'd like to read as a Pandas dataframe, but I'm not sure how to do it and I'd like to avoid outputting to CSV and reading it back. How would I do it?

E.g.

```
string='term_ID,description,frequency,plot_X,plot_Y,plot_size,uniqueness,dispensability,representative,eliminated\r\nGO:0006468,"protein phosphorylation",4.137%, 4.696, 0.927,5.725,0.430,0.000,6468,0\r\nGO:0050821,"protein stabilization, positive",0.045%,-4.700, 0.494,3.763,0.413,0.000,50821,0\r\n'
```

I was splitting the string with

```
fcsv_content=[x.split(',') for x in string.split("\r\n")]
```

But this will not work as some fields have commas inside. What can I do? Could I change the decoding so that this is fixed? 
For some background, I'm using [robobrowser](https://gist.github.com/SamDM/b7e8a13a5529c24291e293ee6ebe2366) to decode the webpage.

Comment: have you tried using ptyhons in built csv module to split your csv string, it will take into account commas which exsist inside quoted strings etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pythons csv module to read and spit your csv. It will take care of things like commas being inside quoted strings and know not to split those. below is a small example using your input string. As you will see in the example below the field `protein stabilization, positive` doesn't get split into separate columns as its a quoted string

```py
import csv

string = 'term_ID,description,frequency,plot_X,plot_Y,plot_size,uniqueness,dispensability,representative,eliminated\r\nGO:0006468,"protein phosphorylation",4.137%, 4.696, 0.927,5.725,0.430,0.000,6468,0\r\nGO:0050821,"protein stabilization, positive",0.045%,-4.700, 0.494,3.763,0.413,0.000,50821,0\r\n'
csv_reader = csv.reader(string.splitlines())
for record in csv_reader:
    print(f'number of fields: {len(record)}, Record: {record}'
```

**OUTPUT**

```
number of fields: 10, Record: ['term_ID', 'description', 'frequency', 'plot_X', 'plot_Y', 'plot_size', 'uniqueness', 'dispensability', 'representative', 'eliminated']
number of fields: 10, Record: ['GO:0006468', 'protein phosphorylation', '4.137%', ' 4.696', ' 0.927', '5.725', '0.430', '0.000', '6468', '0']
number of fields: 10, Record: ['GO:0050821', 'protein stabilization, positive', '0.045%', '-4.700', ' 0.494', '3.763', '0.413', '0.000', '50821', '0']
```

Comment: This is much simpler than what I was trying: I had split strings based on `","`, and was then cleaning and splitting each again. thanks a lot!

Comment: One small question though: is there a simple way to convert the output from `csv_reader` to a list of lists, without reading its content in a loop?

Comment: yeah just use a list comprehension `data = [record for record in csv.reader(string.splitlines())]`